# reactjs local vs deployed issue

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

I have a issue with my reactjs app created with create-react-app. As soon as the app loads it makes an AJAX request to load a json file in the public folder of myapp.

On my local development machine it works if I set path for the json file as "myapp/data.json".

http://localhost:3000/myapp

But when I deploy to github pages, it does not work. To make it work on github pages I have to change the path to "data.json".

https://githubid.github.io/myapp

But then it stops working on local development machine.

How can I make this work on both local and gh-pages deployment work without having to change path each time.

Comment: You can use `Docker` to set different `.env` files for `dev` and `prod`

Comment: @keikai there must be an easier way out.